# Alternating converging sum of infinite inscribed polygons

Tags: geometry, convergence-divergence

Take an equilateral triangle with side length $1$. Then, inscribe the largest possible square in this triangle such that the bottom of the square is a segment of the bottom of the triangle. Then inscribe the largest possible regular pentagon inside this square where the bottom of the pentagon is also a segment of the bottom of the triangle.

Find the area inside the polygons with an odd number of sides and not in the polygons with an even number of sides (shaded area in image).

I've searched for a possible convergence but haven't really had any success. Does anybody see a possible way forward? Is there even an answer to this problem?

[inscribed polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICDd7.jpg)

Also included because I found it relevant: [Nested Regular Polygons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320062/nested-regular-polygons)

Comment: "Large" would mean "biggest possible area."  By regular I mean "equiangular and equilateral." Sorry if my image is poor.

Comment: I changed my problem to "largest possible square" to be consistent with the "regular" requirement for the other polygons.

Comment: It's clear that the area is well-defined, since the sequence being summed is a subsequence of the sequence of all the interstitial areas, which sums to the area of the triangle. So regardless of what the value converges _to_, it's easy to show convergence. Have you done any numerical calculation to get an approximate value?

Comment: I'm working on some non-math-for-fun right now, but I'll get back to this once classes are out and homework is done.